# Differential equations (SO ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

My problem is based on the next differential equation:

$\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 P^2 V'' +rPV' - rV + GP-C = 0.$

Have someone idea how to solve it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to solve for $V(t)$, so that all coefficients are constants since $V$ depends on $t$.
Put $V(t)=e^{\lambda t}$ in $\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 P^2 V'' +rPV'-rV=0$ and solve for $\lambda$. You will probably find two solutions. Then you need to find any solution to the whole ODE. You can find a constant solution if you use $V=D=const$ and plug it into the ODE and solve for D. The general solution, will be $V(t)=c_1 e^{\lambda_1 t}+c_2 e^{\lambda_2 t}+D$, where $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.